# Why is there a down voting option on this website?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

Would it be better that there is only marking up for the questions asked to eliminate the probability that some people would just like to vote others down no matter what the answer? The best answers would be judged by the amount of positive votes. Would it be a good idea for the developers of this website to make a petition for all users to see how many people favour voting down or no voting down?

Comment: Serial voting against someone is generally reversed within a day.

Comment: This question serves as the petition. The amount of up- and down-votes on it (currently +3-11=-8) is a good indication of whether the community agrees with you or not.

Comment: I wrote this question because someone marked 4 of my answers down in 2 minutes. It seemed to be serial voting regardless of the answer. Anyway, I don't care about the votes. The most important thing about this website is what you can learn and what you can teach.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty - good idea to think of this question as a petition. However, only one problem,  I can't vote in this petition :) So whatever the score, add one for me :) Anyway, as I said before, I don't care about the votes, even though the serial voting against me hasn't been reversed. I also tried to delete this question, but it can't be deleted. The most important thing about this website is what you can learn and what you can teach.

Comment: Also, if it was Maria Sharapova who asked this question, rather than the certainly arrogant grumpy old Heisenberg, then there will be a million positive votes :) I should have asked her to post this question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Voting down is a judgment of quality (although on meta it's more about whether people agree or disagree with you since questions can be opinions).

On the main site, you vote up answers that are correct and useful. You vote down questions that are not correct or not useful. If downvotes were eliminated, then it just means the scale will shift and a score of 0 means not useful.

But downvoting also counter-acts incorrect upvotes. Maybe people voted up an answer or question without knowing whether it was completely accurate. There needs to be a way for those who do know to counter-act that.

Plus, things with many downvotes become grayed out or removed from view to indicate that they aren't to be trusted. Without downvotes, bad answers may stay at 0 but good ones also start out at 0 so there's no way to distinguish between bad and just not-yet-upvoted.

So, if you have a + there has to be - for the universe to balance out.

Comment: Good point. However, how about that negative votes don't cancel the positive. Rather they will be like the votes on YouTube and if the negative votes exceed the positive, then the score someone would get is zero and not negative. But one can see the total positive and negative votes, and the voters would be known.

Comment: @Heisenberg Once you get enough rep, not too terribly much but I can't remember the threshold now, you can actually click on the vote and see the number of positive and negative votes. So that feature is there for people who are actually part of the community -- people who haven't been around long enough don't need to know what the ratio is because they can't really judge why it is what it is. Is it because the answer is right or wrong or because a policy is violated with an otherwise interesting question or answer?

Comment: @Heisenberg For example, http://i.stack.imgur.com/j1raQ.png

Comment: You can see vote counts at [1000 rep](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), see also [in more detail](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)

Answer (score 2):

Note that it *costs* reputation points to vote down. So, users cannot just mark down everything in sight *ad infinitum*; they'll eventually run out of karma. And as Al mentioned, the moderators can remove abusive voters.

As for the motivation behind the feature, it is so that people who have established their reputation in the community can use their judgement to suppress excessive upvotes (or just to bury plain bad content). This also prevents users who are asking bad questions or giving bad answers from gaining reputation on the site. It takes less minimum reputation to upvote a question than to downvote; so the downvotes should be coming from more experienced members.

For example, suppose someone asks a question like "what if you shoot a bullet from a spaceship going at the speed of light?" Some new members might think that's a really neat and original question, and vote it up. But more experienced members will know that this question has been asked numerous times before.

Comment: it is called reputation and not karma

Comment: Although it is possible their karma would run out too...

Comment: @user689: Yes the official term is Reputation (TM). But karma is a fun word to use, and synonyms make the world more interesting!

Comment: Actually, our (moderators') ability to remove abusive voters is extremely limited. We get very little information about votes cast. Except in cases where one person is using multiple accounts to upvote each other, there probably isn't much we can do.